# How to update a field of array elements which depends on all elements of array in single iteration?

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `Offer` objects :

```
public class Offer {
    String offerId;
    String offerType; //Can be REGULAR or FASTTRACK
    String ticketId
}
```

For example, if I send a request to buy two offers, the ticketId in the response is supposed to be `<offerId1+offerType1>,<offerId2+offerType2>`

The problem is, I have to first iterate over all offers to generate the ticketId because `ticketId` is comma separated string of offerId+offerType i.e. it depends on all the elements of array. Then I have to iterate the offers again to populate the same `ticketId` in each `Offer` object.

Is there a way I can do this in single iteration ?

Comment: Will the ticket id be same for all the offers?

Comment: @YogeshPatil No, the ticketId for individual offers depends on their offerId and offerType.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it makes sense storing `ticketId` in `Offer` then.

But to your question, you could use a wrapper object which contains a `String` - the `ticketId` and store a reference to said wrapper in your `Offer`. After iterating through the `Offer`s and generating the `ticketId` you can store it in your wrapper and all `Offer`s can access it through their wrapper-reference.

Comment: Actually this is not the exact problem. I had minimised my problem statement but the problem is more or less same as this. :)

Comment: But then I will have to refer to `ticketId` using `offer.wrapper.ticketId` right?

Comment: Yes, but in Java it is concention to use getter- and setter-methods to acces variables of a class. Using this technique you could hide the fact that it is a wrapper from the caller of the class.And what have you updated?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of getters and setters. I am just using dot to make it readable.